# How to remove some of the TimeSeries titles in a AChartEngine Time Series View

Tags: android, time-series, title, achartengine, android-graphview

As a workaround of not being able to change colors of selected points in a series on an 
**AChartEngine** Time Chart, I was using an additional series for each point whose color has to
be changed.  I need to disable series titles for those additional series.

Using empty string as the argument to the Time Series construtor:

```
TimeSeries ts = TimeSeries("");
```

still results in the line-and-point symbol being placed with empty series title string
under the X-axis labels for each such series.

It would be a desirable feature for `AChartEngine` to remove both the line-and-point symbol and the
series title string for a series created with a null argument to the TimeSeries construtor call:

```
TimeSeries ts = TimeSeries(null);
```

But this currently resulted in **nullPointerException** instead.

Would the **AChartEngine** developers consider the above suggestion and until then,
is there a way to remove some of the `TimeSeries` titles from a `AChartEngine Time Series View`?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Best regards.